# Out of memory, при последовательном запуске цепочки методов

Tags: java, android, rxjava

Здравствуйте! У меня образовалась проблема в которой я не знаю куда копать.
Есть класс с которым я работаю через RxJava. Необходимо рекурсивно его запускать последовательно n-ое количество раз, но на запуске 20-25, приложение вылетает с ошибкой Out of memory.

```
public void listSong (String keywords){

        Log.e("RxJavaX", "keywords: " + keywords);


        Observer<List<ObjectTrack>> observer = new Observer<List<ObjectTrack>>() {
            @Override
            public void onSubscribe(Disposable d) {
                Log.e("RxJavaX", "onSubscribe: ");
            }

            @Override
            public void onNext(List value) {

                insertToBase.insertSongsToBase(value);

                Log.e("RxJavaX", "onNext: " + value);
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(Throwable e) {
                Log.e("RxJavaX", "onError: Names");
            }

            @Override
            public void onComplete() {



             //   for (int i = 1; i<=ejectSongsFromBase.ejectSongsNamesFromBase(PopSongs.class).size();i++){
                if(numNamesSong <= sizeOfList){

                    listSong(ejectSongsFromBase.ejectSongsNamesFromBase(PopSongs.class).get(numNamesSong).getTrackArtist() + " " + ejectSongsFromBase.ejectSongsNamesFromBase(PopSongs.class).get(numNamesSong).getTrackName());
                    numNamesSong++;
                }


          //  threadParseFree = true;
            Log.e("RxJavaX", "onComplete: All Done! " + ejectSongsFromBase.ejectSongsFromBase(ObjectTrack.class));
        }
    };

    parserPage.getTrackList(Constants, keywords).subscribe(observer);
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте 2 версию rxJava и в нём Flowable вместо Observable - он должен будет, по идее, автоматом решить эту проблему

Comment: Да, точно. Забыл уточнить, использую RxJava 2. Спасибо, сейчас попробую.